# Access data attribute value in angular 2

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a form with a id :

```
<form id="dummyForm">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="submit" value="click me">
</form>
```

and a div with data attribute, which contains form's id :

```
<div attr.data-form-id="dummyForm" (click)=hideForm()>Click to hide</div>
```

how can I get the `data-form-id` value in `hideform()` function. so that I can hide the form.

Any Help?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
<div attr.data-form-id="dummyForm" 
    #me 
    (click)="hideForm(me.getAttribute('data-form-id'))">
  Click to hide
</div>
```

Comment: That was the plan :D