# How to get data attribute value in component.ts in angular 2

Tags: angular-material2

I am trying to get value of data attribute inside component.ts in angular2.

1) form2.component.html

```
<md-select  placeholder = "BedRooms" [formControl]="userForm.controls['bedRooms']" >
    <md-option #bedRoom  *ngFor="let bedRooms of formSettings?.prices?.pricingParams?.bedRooms" [value] = bedRooms.title [attr.data-price] = bedRooms.price (click)="test(bedRoom)"> {{bedRooms?.title}} </md-option>
</md-select>
```

How to get value of data-price in test function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access data attribute value in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42198610/access-data-attribute-value-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access the value of `data-price` from reference `bedRoom` as below.

```
bedRoom.getAttribute('data-price');
```